# Gemini regression testing — dynamic rootUrl

Tags: unit-testing, regression-testing

I am looking to be able to enter a custom command such as the the one below to kick off several suites of Gemini regression tests (https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini).

The command I am using works, but I can't figure out how to pass a custom `GEMINI_URL` variable I created through to override the `rootURL` in the .yml config file.

This command tests the rootUrl in the config file and works fine:

`gulp test:gemini-local`

This command works too, the same exact way, but it should be testing the localhost:3000 domain instead of rootUrl:

`GEMINI_URL=http://localhost:3000/testsite/ gulp test:gemini-local`

Ideally, this `GEMINI_URL` variable/value would be able to be passed to both the `rootUrl` (for testing), as well as the `gridUrl` (for screen captures).

Here is the current working code in my gulp test.js file, but it only ever tests the `rootUrl` and never the dynamic URL that I am trying to insert into the process:

```
/**
 * Gemini update locally
 */
gulp.task('test:gemini-update-local',
  geminiUpdate('local')
);

/**
 * Gemini update (on SauceLab)
 */
gulp.task('test:gemini-update',
  geminiUpdate('saucelabs')
);

/**
 * Gemini test locally
*/
gulp.task('test:gemini-local',
  geminiTest('local')
);

/**
 * Gemini test (on SauceLab)
 */
gulp.task('test:gemini',
  geminiTest('saucelabs')
);

function geminiUpdate(where) {
  // override rootUrl
  var geminiTestUrlSwitch = process.env.GEMINI_URL ? ' -r ' + process.env.GEMINI_URL : '';

  var command = utils.escapeShellArg(config.paths.root + '/node_modules/.bin/gemini') + ' update' +
                ' -c tests/gemini/.gemini-' + where + '.yml ' +
                ' tests/gemini/tests/' +
               geminiTestUrlSwitch;

  return plugins.shell.task([
command
  ]);
}

function geminiTest(where) {
  // override rootUrl
  var geminiTestUrlSwitch = process.env.GEMINI_URL ? ' -r ' +     process.env.GEMINI_URL : '';

  var command = utils.escapeShellArg(config.paths.root + '/node_modules/.bin/gemini') + ' update' +
                ' -c tests/gemini/.gemini-' + where + '.yml ' +
                ' tests/gemini/tests/' +
                ' --reporter html --reporter flat' +
               geminiTestUrlSwitch;

  return plugins.shell.task([
    command
  ]);
}
```

I can't find any reference to doing this in the documentation ([Commands](https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini/blob/master/doc/commands.md), [Tests](https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini/blob/master/doc/tests.md), or [Config](https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini/blob/master/doc/config.md) MD files).

Any pointers would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Gemini Configuration** documentation, I found the answer I needed, more or less:

`gemini_root_url=http://example.com gemini test`

A previous developer had attempted/created the same functionality via gulp and javascript, but this does not seem to be necessary (any more?), at least with version 2.1.1.  As such, I've stripped out all `geminiTestUrlSwitch`-related code from the sample above for the final version.

Check the **Overriding Settings** section at the bottom of https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini/blob/master/doc/config.md